# How to Group Json Output in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.4

is it possible to group/rearrange JSON output from laravel ?  i want to group it before it send to view by system, so i need it to be done in server side not client side.

Lets said i have JSON structured like this :

`id, name, date`

or in example, is like this :

```
[[
{"id" : "1", "name" : "A", "date" : "2017-01-01"},
{"id" : "2", "name" : "B", "date" : "2017-01-01"},
{"id" : "3", "name" : "C", "date" : "2017-01-01"},
{"id" : "4", "name" : "D", "date" : "2018-01-01"},
{"id" : "5", "name" : "E", "date" : "2018-01-01"},
]]
```

is it possible to group it to be something like this ?

```
[
    {"2017-01-01":[
        {"id":"1","name":"A"},
        {"id":"2","name":"B"},
        {"id":"3","name":"C"}
    ]},
    {"2018-01-01":[
        {"id":"4","name":"D"},
        {"id":"5","name":"E"},
    ]},
]
```

(In case you need to look my JSON Controller) This is my JSON Controller :

```
public function harga($id)
{
  $harga = harga::whereHas('produk', function ($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('id',$id);
  })->get();
  return response()->json([$harga],200);
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use groupBy on your query:

```
public function harga($id)
{
  $harga = harga::whereHas('produk', function ($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('id',$id);
  })->get()->groupBy(column_name_you_want_to_group_by);
  return response()->json([$harga],200);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its work, i doesn't know its will be that easy in Laravel. And thanks too for write it in my controller's code. :)

Comment: For me worked using groupBy after get(), the way you did. (Using before was throwing error)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupBy` method to do it:

```
return response()->json($harga->groupBy('date'), 200);
```

Comment: Nice answers, its a correct answers, but sorry i cant make your answer as the most helpful answer because someone already answer more complete answer than you in the same time. Anyway Thanks so much for helping !

Answer (score 0):

In Controller it is possible to do that as below

```
 js = "your json";
 $jsArray = json_decode($js, true);
    $jsArray = $jsArray[0];
    $newJsArr = [];
    foreach ($jsArray as $j) {
        $newJsArr[$j['date']][] = ["id" => $j['id'], "name" => $j['name']];
    }
    $newJsArr = json_encode([$newJsArr]);
```